# Draft.js VS CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, draftjs

Can we say Draft.JS is an alternative to CKEditor?

I have read about Draft.js and so far what I concluded is that it's written only for React.js where CKEditor on the other hand can be used in PHP, JS and all.

Answer (score 1):

DraftJS has a lot more functionality, but it's also got virtually no community support by comparison so you're basically on your own as far as unlocking that functionality goes.

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view draft.js won't replace the CKEditor. it's completely based on your requirement with the editor.

- CKEditor is an stable WYSIWYG editor with advanced plugins.
- Draft.js is an REACT based WYSIWYG editor component with the simple editorial behavior.